# openapi-generator python name 'AnyOf' is not defined

Tags: python, fastapi, openapi, openapi-generator

I used open-api generator to generate a Python client from a openapi specification which comes from fastapi.
When i try to use the generated client or run pytest, i have the following error:

```
NameError: name 'AnyOf' is not defined
```

Is `AnyOf` a missing class ? Or should it be imported from smomewhere ?

##### Versions

- **open-api generator**: docker image v7.1.0
- **Python**: 3.10.4
- **"openapi"**:"3.1.0"
- **pip freeze**:

```
annotated-types==0.6.0
attrs==23.1.0
coverage==7.3.2
iniconfig==2.0.0
openapi-client==1.0.0
packaging==23.2
pluggy==1.3.0
py==1.11.0
pydantic==2.5.0b1
pydantic_core==2.14.1
pytest==7.1.3
pytest-cov==4.1.0
pytest-randomly==3.15.0
python-dateutil==2.8.2
six==1.16.0
tomli==2.0.1
typing_extensions==4.8.0
urllib3==2.0.7
```

- **Expected**: the geerated client works perfectly
- **What I tried**: reseach about `AnyOf`
  I could delete the `AnyOf` from the generated code but I don't think it's the good solution

## Simple Reproductible example

Python APP

```py
from typing import List, Optional, Union

from fastapi import FastAPI

app = FastAPI()


@app.get("/")
def read_root():
    return {"Hello": "World"}


@app.get("/items/{item_id}",
    summary="Return an amazing list.",
    response_model=Union[List[str], List[int]]
    )
def read_item(item_id: int, q: Union[str, None] = None):
    if q is not None:
        return [q, q]
    else:
        return [item_id, item_id]
    #return {"item_id": item_id, "q": q}
```

- run it with `uvicorn main:app --reload`
- get the openapi spec from `wget http://127.0.0.1:8000/openapi.json`
- generate de python client

```
docker run --rm -v ${PWD}:/local openapitools/openapi-generator-cli:v7.1.0 generate -i /local/openapi.json -g python -o /local/out/python
```

- create virtual env
- install python client dependencies
- run pytest

NOTE: The issue comes when the `response_model=Union[List[str], List[int]]` is introduced in the python code.

Comment: You've provided no means to reproduce the error. Consider including a minimal reproducible example of the schema and the instruction via which you've generated the client.

Comment: @PawełRubin Sorry for the miss, example added